# Fb app invite with referral code

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am interested in using FB App Invites and app links functionality so users can invite their friends. I want to be able to pass referral code as well.

I don't have a web server nor do I know if I should for this purpose. I am just too confused about the process

I followed the docs and I was able to generate an app link using FB hosting tool in the form of https://fb.me/123456789

I can use that in the App invite dialog that I will integrate in my android app.

Now my question is, how can I add referral code to that so when the new user download the app, the newly installed android app will receive that referral code?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/bestpractices#incentivize_invite_accepts

Comment: I don't see anywhere how to add the referral code

Comment: You put it into your app link URL.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?maybe an example? I know that fb strips the info

Comment: Why would FB strip any info, if that is the way the recommend themselves in their documentation? // App-Links are extensively documented under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks and http://applinks.org/

Comment: I used the applink that fb provided and  I put ?referral=123 at the end of it and I put it in browser. I got directed into google play while the referral info was taken out. I dont see it in the documentation what you suggsted

Comment: What do you mean by “the applink that fb provided”? App Links are something that you have to setup up yourself.

Comment: I used the fb Webtool that generates the app link based on the FB hosting Api. Here is the link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android  ,you will see the "create link" and based on that I got the link that I posted in question (offcourse different ID than 123456789)

Answer (score 3):

Facebook's policy does not allow awarding for (all)invites/sharing/commenting/liking any more.

You could anyway implement it like airbnb that you award the user who is downloading the app with something, when being referred. If you only want to track conversions you should utilize [Facebook's insights dashboar](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/analytics)

### Update

If you want to track Google Play reffs utilize this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#general-campaigns

Comment: I didn't talk about rewards in my question. My question is :how can I add referral code to the app link so the user download the app, the app will process the referral code?

Comment: FYI: You are allowed to reward for _successful_ invites. User A invites B, and B then joins the app – then you are allowed to reward A for that.

Comment: For a app invite you can not pass something to the app executable, due to the fact that the app is not installed on the phone and so the user will be taken to google play / App Store where any url parameters will be striped (most likely).

Comment: @Snake See a solution for google play within my update

Comment: @Markus, you can using fb, it's called I guess deferred deep linking. Once the app is installed then fb opens it and pass info to it. I know fb talked about it but I couldn't really understand how to implement it.. I will upvote your answer because it is through google but I want it through fb